# How do I get past "SFP Validation Failed" on a SFP-GE-T transceiver on a Nexus 5548UP?

Tags: cisco, sfp, cisco-nexus

I inserted a SFP-GE-T (Gigabit RJ-45) transceiver in my Nexus 5548UP and I got "access down" "SFP Validation Failed" in show interface.

According to the [Cisco Gigabit Ethernet Transceivers Compability Matrix](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/OL_6981.html#wp139256) the SFP-GE-T is compatible with the 5548UP.

How do I get past "SFP Validation Failed" on a SFP-GE-T transceiver on a Nexus 5548UP?

Comment: Silly question, have you tried reseating the module?

Comment: Totally valid question @Zypher.  Reseating doesn't fix it for me :)

Comment: Are you sure it's not counterfeit? Did you check the serial number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Configure the port as `speed 1000` **before** inserting the SFP-GE-T transceiver.

If you have the transceiver inserted already, remove it and then set `speed 1000` on the port.  Upon re-insertion the SFP should come up :)