# How do I get past “SFP Validation Failed” on a FET-10G transceiver on a Nexus 5548UP?

Tags: cisco, sfp, cisco-nexus

I inserted a FET-10G (Fabric Extender Transceiver) SFP transceiver in my Nexus 5548UP and I got "access down" "SFP Validation Failed" in show interface.

FET-10Gs came with my 2232's so I figured they'd be plug and play.  This is with a blank port configuration.

How do I get past "SFP Validation Failed" on a FET-10G transceiver on a Nexus 5548UP?

Comment: What version are you running on the 5548?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  Please reopen.  The solution for this is different.  I know the answer and was trying to get this on ServerFault so other people running into it would have an easy answer available from Google.

Comment: I also fell for the temptation of just skimming over the text where it says FET-10G here and SFP-GE-T [there](http://serverfault.com/questions/339957) and wondered for a while why you would want a nearly exactly duplicate question re-opened - the wording is quite similar

Comment: Is the solution different between the two?  Why not simply update the other question/answer to apply to both?

Comment: Are you sure it's not counterfeit? Did you check the serial number?

Comment: So were you planning on posting the Answer if you know if already???

Comment: I was going to post the answer when the question was closed :)  Posting now.

Comment: @syneticon-dj, I totally understand :)  That was my laziness in asking two very similar questions by altering the text of one to suit the second.  Thank you for understanding :)

Comment: @Joseph the 5548 is running NX-OS 5.0(3)N2(1) :)

Comment: @MikeyB, they are authentic SFP's verified with, for example "sh int e1/1 trans".  They show up as CISCO-FINISAR and they do work when the port configuration is corrected :)  Thank you for your interest :)

Comment: @AlainO'Dea: I ask as some transceivers entered our supply chain a while ago that show up correctly and validate under certain conditions but are counterfeit. They do show up as CISCO-FINISAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the port's **switchport mode** to **fex-fabric** will clear the **SFP Validation Failed** message.  You can do this while the SFP transceiver is inserted.

Example setting up port 1 to allow fabric extension:

```
conf
int e1/1
switchport mode fex-fabric
```

The trouble is the order in which I thought this would work.  I was trying to verify the transceiver hardware before getting into software configuration of the ports, but the transceiver expects a certain configuration first.  This configuration can be changed while the transceiver is inserted.